# Bottom Sheet no se muestra - Flutter

Tags: flutter

Necesito que aparezca un `BottomSheet` cuando presiono sobre un `IconButton`:

```
IconButton(
           icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
           iconSize: 25,
           splashRadius: 20,
           onPressed: () {
                MyHomePage();
           },
           tooltip: "Opciones")
```

En un tutorial que estaba siguiendo debería aparecer el bottomshet mediante la llamada a `MyHomePage`, pero no me aparece nada, este es el código que tengo:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
    final String title;

    @override
    _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    String _selectedItem = "";
    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
                children: [
                    RaisedButton(onPressed: () => _onButtonPressed()),
                    Text(_selectedItem, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30))
                ],
            ),
        ));
    }

    void _onButtonPressed() {
        showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return Column(
                children: [ListTile(title: Text("BottomSheet"))],
              );
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Acabo de realizar una prueba de tu código [https://codepen.io/eduardojl-the-reactor/pen/eYdNeqe](https://codepen.io/eduardojl-the-reactor/pen/eYdNeqe), y si me funciona, no se si el error venga de como llamas tu HomePage.

Comment: En el código que probaste, desde el método principal, estas llamando directamente a la clase `MyHomePage` que es un `StatefulWidget`,  mientras que en mi caso, desde el método principal estoy llamando a una clase 'Main' que es un `StatelessWidget` y dentro de esa clase `Main` recién estoy queriendo llamar a `MyHomePage` mediante un `IconButton`, será que este es problema por tener un `StatelessWidget` en vez de un `StatefulWidget`?

Comment: puedes poner tu código completo por que no logro entender como es que lo llamas

Comment: Aquí te lo dejo: https://codepen.io/leonidas21/pen/RwGPzNy

Comment: revisando tu código veo que en el botón de opciones solo llamas a MyHomePage, ahí quieres redireccionar tu aplicaición?

Comment: Te dejo dos ejemplos dependiendo de si quieres llamar a la ruta HomePage desde el botón Opciones, o si quieres que el Home Page se muestre en el BottomSheet, https://codepen.io/eduardojl-the-reactor/pen/eYdNeqe, https://codepen.io/eduardojl-the-reactor/pen/mdredGv

Comment: Me quedo con el primero, gracias, si lo pones de respuesta la acepto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es el ejemplo de tu código completo donde modifico tu código para que el BottomSheet se muestre al dar click en el IconButton.

La función se ejecuta dentro de la clase Main, y no dentro de el HomePage

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(Main());

class Main extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent),
    );
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Social",
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.white, primarySwatch: Colors.teal),
      home: Scaffold(
        drawer: Builder(
          builder: (context) => Drawer(
            child: ListView(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                children: [
                  UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                      accountName: Text("Nombre"),
                      accountEmail: Text("Correo Electronico"),
                      currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                        child: Text("N"),
                      )),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Inicio'),
                    leading: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
                    onTap: () {},
                  )
                ]),
          ),
        ),
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Social"), actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: () {},
              splashRadius: 20,
              tooltip: "Buscar",
              iconSize: 25)
        ]),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: 1,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) => Card(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 10,
                              top: 10,
                              right: 5,
                              bottom: 10,
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                      SnackBar(
                                        content: Text("click"),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                  child: CircleAvatar(
                                    child: Text("N"),
                                    radius: 20,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                          left: 10,
                                          bottom: 5,
                                        ),
                                        child: Text(
                                          "N",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          maxLines: 3,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                        child: Row(
                                          children: [
                                            Icon(
                                              Icons.timer_outlined,
                                              size: 12,
                                            ),
                                            Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                left: 5,
                                              ),
                                              child: Text(
                                                "Fecha y Hora",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 12,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                                  iconSize: 25,
                                  splashRadius: 20,
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    _onButtonPressed(context);
                                  },
                                  tooltip: "Opciones",
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 500,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    elevation: 0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 10,
                      bottom: 10,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () {},
          label: Text(""),
          icon: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFE0E0E0),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onButtonPressed(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return MyHomePage();
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _selectedItem = "";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [Text(_selectedItem, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30))],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```